# how link the home dir of two linux distro on different partitions

Tags: ubuntu

I have dual booted my 500gb drive with Ubuntu and mint. On doing so I made a separate partitions for each. So now I have two different home directories on different OS. Its really difficult to get around. Now how can I make it a common home directory on a single partition. Without uninstalling. And how can uninstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate partition as you said, then follow this guide to move your `/home` mount point :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Instructions will be the same on Mint I guess...